Why the discrepancy between using the nCr function and counting?
So there is this quite elementary high school problem that i was solving which goes something like "A committee of 4 persons is to be formed from 2 ladies, 2 old men and 4 young men such that it includes at least one lady. At least one old man and at most 2 young men. Then the total number of ways in which committee can be formed is?"
The first approach which yields the correct answer(41) is to just count cases of 0,1,2 young guys which is pretty straightforward and is also correct.
But my second method that i have spent considerable thought into is to :-
Select one lady and one old man  by 2C1*2C1 now we have filled all the requirement of the question. Now we have 6 people remaining with 2 empty spots, so why not just select 2 people from the 6 directly(By 6C2)? this would cover all the cases too of 2 young men, 1 young,1 old.... So i am very stuck as to why this yields 60 instead of the expected 41. (even more interesting is that 41 is prime)

Please avoid chitchating. "So there is this quite elementary high school problem that i was solving which goes something like" is unnecessary. See How to ask good question.

Sincere apologies, i didnt wanna come off as just dumping assignments on here!.

Also, I don't see how $41$ been prime is interesting, why do you thing that?

well if the solution could be achieved directly by the second method then the solution would not be prime, it being prime told me that this is wrong but just dont know why!

The way to avoid looking like you're dumping an assignment is by showing your work, as you already did after the question, not using filler text.

i will keep that in mind next time! Thank you.

You are double counting the ones that have two ladies, once when the first lady is the one you select in particular and then you pick the second in the last two people and again when the second is the one you select in particular.  The two old men are similar.  The committee of two ladies and two old men you have counted four times.
